# How can i set text to textview when it is rotated and see it correctly?

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation, textview

I have two textview in my layout.
and this is my layout shape.[image: layout with 2 relativelayout in left and right] and in this layout i have 2 `relativelayout` that they are child of my main`relativelayout`. this 2 child `layout` filled main `layout's` left and right. and 2 `textview` are set to `alignParentLeft` and `alignParentRight` of 2 child `layout's` as you see in this picture. now in my activity i change `textviews` rotation to 90 to see them in up to down shape. when text of textviews are small there is not any problem, but when it is larger than screen_width/2, then i see that `textviews` are inside `eachother`. how can i solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of struggling i found that do these steps:

1. in Manifest file `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`. this code force the layout to created in landscape mode.
2. in my layout i created 2 `RelativeLayout` that every one of them's height is (width_of_screen)/2.(i do this programatically). and one is set to AlignParentTop and another set to AlignParentBottom.
3. then i added textviews. textview one to Bottom of Top layout and textview two to Top of Bottom layout.
4. then i added my imageview as background for this 2 textview. and i placed it inside ParentLayout and set centervertical and centerhorizontal true for this imageview.

after doing this steps there is no need to set rotation for textviews and every things work fine.

Thanks every one.